# Field missing using apex-lang SoqlBuilder

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I'm using Apex-lang to build queries. http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/

**problem:**
A custom lookup field won't show up in the generated query.

If I duplicate the SoqlBuilder class and use the new class,
the custom field will show up.

Could there be some FLS on class level that I'm missing?
I tried this using Anonymous Apex.

Comment: What API version is the non-working class? Can you confirm the API version of the two classes are the same?

Comment: The non-working class is API version 13.0
If I change it to 28.0 it is working.

Do you know by any chance the creteria for fields to show up in API 13.0?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Here's a resource that shows what has changed in each API Version. I'm wondering if lookup fields weren't added until after API 13.0 http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/whats_new.htm

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. I'll play with the API Version to see where it fails. You may add your comments as an answer, so I can mark it as the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API version of the classes are different, this could be causing the issue. New features are versioned within the API, to maintain backward compatibility. If a feature was added after the API version of the class, it will not be accessible.

Take a look at this [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/whats_new.htm) to see what features were added in what API version.

Comment: lookups to junction objects were added after v13